# Process.Start (Weird issue)

Tags: .net, internet-explorer

Something strange here. I have *very* long URL and it's working fine "when" i directly paste it to address bar of Internet Explorer:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=hybrid&sensor=false&path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:5|40.262043212854,28.9574884865954|40.2620393471008,28.9577391646903|40.2620333177299,28.9581300766863|40.261331625691,28.9581449735233|40.2613229341457,28.9575062426388|40.262043212854,28.9574884865954&markers=color:blue|label:0|40.262043212854,28.9574884865954&markers=color:blue|label:1|40.2620393471008,28.9577391646903&markers=color:blue|label:2|40.2620333177299,28.9581300766863&markers=color:blue|label:3|40.261331625691,28.9581449735233&markers=color:blue|label:4|40.2613229341457,28.9575062426388&markers=color:blue|label:5|40.262043212854,28.9574884865954
```

and when i try to invoke the same URL using "Process.Start("iexplore.exe", ..."), i get a dialog box with error saying the resource cannot be downloaded. I try this and get error:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=hybrid&sensor=false&path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:5|40.262043212854,28.9574884865954|40.2620393471008,28.9577391646903|40.2620333177299,28.9581300766863|40.261331625691,28.9581449735233|40.2613229341457,28.9575062426388|40.262043212854,28.9574884865954&markers=color:blue|label:0|40.262043212854,28.9574884865954&markers=color:blue|label:1|40.2620393471008,28.9577391646903&markers=color:blue|label:2|40.2620333177299,28.9581300766863&markers=color:blue|label:3|40.261331625691,28.9581449735233&markers=color:blue|label:4|40.2613229341457,28.9575062426388&markers=color:blue|label:5|40.262043212854,28.9574884865954");
```

Note that decoding/encoding URL has no effect on getting rid of the error.

What's wrong here?

**Update/EDIT:** When i try "Process.Start" with "firefox.exe" along with the same URL above, it works like a charm. And if i shorten the link even to like this, i still get error using Process.Start + IE:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=hybrid&sensor=false");
```

I'm really lost here.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem, it works fine for me as it is.

Comment: it also works fine for me as is, are you sure you didn't make a typo?

Comment: It works fine for me too.  I can't think of a particular reason that it would differ from machine to machine.  I do recall that I had issues with `Process.Start` when using a "mailto" URL that was too long because it contained too many addresses in the "To" field.  I never did determine exactly what the character limit was but I think it was about 2000 characters, while yours is not even close to that long.  Is this an IE or .NET error?  If it's IE, what is displayed in the address bar?  What happens if you specify a different browser?

Comment: There may not be enough info to provide a precise answer.  At ~700 characters, your query shouldn't be running into any size limitations of IE and/or .NET.  Without knowing the version of either, though, that's uncertain.  The error you report is not described on the Process.Start ref page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx), so it may triggered by the static maps API.  You didn't mention which version or license you were using, but there are limits.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/ for details.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers! I use IE8 for specific reasons and no special setting has been done. It's all default. Also there's no limitation about static maps api restriction including char limit either for IE or maps api itself, as you said. I'm using free version of statics api, and if it the error was because of maps api, it also should have happened when accessing directly through IE. The error i get is this:

http://i.imgur.com/umXxED5.jpg

The weird part is, as i pointed out, the same URL works like a charm when i directly paste to address bar of IE and hit ENTER on the follow.

Comment: Does passing the URL in as a [ProcessStartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) argument make any difference at all?

Comment: I think it makes no difference, adding ProcessStartInfo. It's strange behaviour of IE, Firefox, Opera and Chrome doesn't fire any error.